# Python exercise break command

Tags: python

I need fast help with school exercise. I have to remove command break from following code and make the code work correctly without that break command in it. I would be very thankful for advice.

```
city = 'Brooklyn'
searchable = input('Insert searchable symbol: ')
for index,symbol in enumerate(city):    # for every index
    if symbol == searchable:            # control if examining is found
        print("Symbol has been found at index: ", index) # if yes, print index
        break # stop search
    else:
        print('Symbol',searchable,'is not represented in word',city)
```

Comment: First piece of advice: use the indentation to make clear what the lines look like. ;)

Comment: Isn't it cheating to come here since this is school? ;)

Comment: Can you use a function and `return`? That's a simple transformation that avoids `break` :)

Comment: I guess the teacher wants him/her to... use... well, another type of loop maybe?

Comment: Hint: `for` loops *also* can have an `else` block. Try dedenting the block you already have and see what happens.

Comment: You should know how to translate any for statement into a while statement. Once you do that, you can just add a "done" flag and add "and not done" to the while check. This is very rarely the best way to do it (in fact, if you ever find yourself doing it, consider a break, and all of the suggestions on this question), but it's worth learning how to do it, and why it's annoying.

Comment: @iCodez: many teachers don't consider it cheating to ask for advice on SO. Asking for a complete answer is a different story, and copying and pasting code from an answer without understanding it even more so, of course.

Comment: Yeah, well, a full answer he/she got :(

Comment: @iCodez: many teachers/schools are teaching collaborative efforts (as part of| the means by which) you get answers.  The transformations at University libraries from quiet areas to group study is growing.  Question is is this teacher using that method to grade this assignment.  But to be honest, it's what user2904150 will be doing afterward the class is over.  So it's a means to another means.

Comment: I was just saying that sometimes it's better to try it yourself, even if the results are not as good as those you'd get elsewhere.  Practice makes perfect.  If anything, my comment was saying that you will never learn if you don't try.  Asking questions is fine, but just copy/pasting code means you never learn to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`str` has `find` method, which searches string, returns the occurence index if found, -1 if not:

```
city = 'Brooklyn'
searchable = input('Insert searchable symbol: ')
index = city.find(searchable)
if index >= 0:
    print("Symbol has been found at index: ", index) # if yes, print index
else:
    print('Symbol',searchable,'is not represented in word',city)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
city = 'Brooklyn'

searchable = raw_input('Insert searchable symbol: ')

print [idx for idx, ele in enumerate(city) if searchable == ele]
```

Comment: Not quite the equivalent of the one stated by OP. This one would spit two positions for searchable = "o", and the original code would stop running after the first one.